# In object cache is there an Item typeMapping for json objects

Tags: object-cache

In Tridion Sites 9.1 we seem to be battling between tomcat caching settings and the Tridion Ojbect Caching.  We have a JavaScript REST call getting a list of items from the delivery database, but the page isn't rendering all the latest list of articles.  So it seems like there is some kind of timing or caching issue.  I can see there is a way to call out caching on item types like page and binary -

Is there a specific typeMapping for json objects?

Comment: Yes, that would typically be the `ComponentPresentation` item type in `cd_storage_conf.xml`, assuming the JSON was created by a combination of a Component and Component Template.  How is your JSON rendered and published into Content Delivery? How can you tell it's a caching issue and when do you get the latest content?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to use ComponentPresentation, that causes a number of errors for me.  I'm fairly certain it's a caching issue, because we're creating a list of news articles using dynamic components.  The list is showing the correct items, and the individual articles are displaying the correct content to the user.  But the metadata and the body text that is added to the detail view of the articles is only correct on the first load of the detail view of the article.  I think it has something to do with the razor template, but was wondering if we could resolve from activeMQ.

Comment: For anyone else that might be having a similar issue.  Although part of the solution was to have activeMQ properly configured. tomcat can have its caching enabled or disabled in its context.xml.  But tomcat does a thing by default to try to reuse the resources for custom Java tags.  In the tomcat web.xml there is a jsp servlet param called enablePooling.  We resolved our issue by adding this to the jsp servlet and disabling it.`
        <init-param>
            <param-name>enablePooling</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>`